# Why doesn't SFDC allow MIXED_DML_OPERATIONs anymore?

Tags: apex, sobject, dml, exception, setup

Okay, I know very well by now that SFDC does not want and often does not allow us simply insert and/or update Setup and/or "Non-setup" sObjects in the same context anymore, something I used to do with impunity when I first started developing Apex.

I've also noticed that it is increasingly neurotic in finding and diagnosing these exceptions, especially when tests are run from the web-ui (instead of Eclipse or the Ant migration tool).

I'm curious whether this is "just" a security concern (i.e. someone might abuse mixed DML to create a backdoor) or whether there are other considerations that would/should make such mixing undesirable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now use `System.runAs` to skirt around the limitation, but only for tests. Note that using `System.runAs` counts as a DML statement, so you cannot infinitely jump around between users. See the documentation on testing [Using the runAs Method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm).

The "why" is that many setup objects can't be mixed with normal records because of the complexity involved with setup objects. For example, creating a new user normally causes a recalculation of sharing rules for that user, and changing a profile's "View All Data" permission might also cause a massive recalculation operation.

In addition, I believe such calculations are deferred, which means that a change to a user or profile might result in allowing users to modify records they otherwise shouldn't be able to as a result of the change, but only during the same transaction.

Comment: At DF13 in the Meet the Developers session your reason of the change to a user or profile was brought up as the primary reason.

Comment: I agree. Any test I would write would be for specifically testing limited permission profiles. It's not normally necessary to use other "setup" objects in casual testing.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I can't and won't quibble about normal, but I'm finding more and more that employers and clients are making heavy use of the custom settings objects, which I imagine you realize are "setup" objects.   As this data ties into triggers and validation rules, I often find it is necessary to populate these (often many of these) for my tests.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I am aware that I can use System.runAs, but I'm finding it annoying to fit/retrofit it into my code to make sure my tests pass... and while I didn't get specific errors from too many runAs calls, I did notice erratic results, as if either some data was being forgotten or data was being updated out of the expected sequence.